# How do I setState for a nested object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react by building a weather api. I make an API call and store it in state.

```
  state = {
        forecasts: {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            forecasts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const endpoint = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/207931?apikey=KEY&language=en&details=true&metric=true`;
        fetch(endpoint)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                'forecasts.isLoaded': true,
                'forecasts.forecasts': result.DailyForecasts,
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                'forecasts.isLoaded': true,
                'forecasts.error': error
            });
        })
    }
```

When I pass this down as props, I get no data?

```
<WeatherOverview weather={this.state.forecasts}/>
```

Comment: please provide the code where you pass it down as props

Comment: @Dani - I've edited the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: If your state only has the `forecasts` object in it, you could just remove the nesting and then only update the values you'd like and let React deal with the shallow merge. `this.setState({ isLoaded: true, error });` which would result in this state: `{ error, isLoaded: true, forecasts: [] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the entire previous object and then override some of its keys. You should also use the form of `setState` that takes a function because you want to reference the previous value of `state.forecasts`:

```js
.then((result) => {
            this.setState(state => ({
                forecasts: {
                    ...state.forecasts,
                    isLoaded: true,
                    forecasts: result.DailyForecasts,
                },
            }));
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState(state => ({
                forecasts: {
                    ...state.forecasts,
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error: error,
                },
            }));
        })
```

or you may want entirely new objects to wipe out the previous error state:

```js
.then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                forecasts: {
                    error: null,
                    isLoaded: true,
                    forecasts: result.DailyForecasts,
                },
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState(state => ({
                forecasts: {
                    forecasts: [],
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error: error,
                },
            }));
        })
```

Comment: Spreading gives me the following error 'state is not defined'

Comment: @johnst123v notice that Ross is passing an arrow function to `setState` which defines a local param `state`. This is how you should be setting a nested state value.

Answer (score -2):

you are not passing the state correctly, you need to pass the state without quotation marks

```
this.setState({
 'forecasts.isLoaded': true,
 'forecasts.forecasts': result.DailyForecasts,
});
```

should be like this:

```
    this.setState({
     forecasts: {
      ...state.forecasts,
      isLoaded:true,
      forecasts:result.DailyForecasts},
   });
```

Comment: I get the following error then - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: @johnst123v it replaces the `forecasts` object with an new object that's missing some properties, so it's unintentionally losing some state data at the same time.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeah you're right i should include the spread operator, my bad